# JSON.NET and Replacing @ Sign in XML to JSON converstion

Tags: xml, json, json.net

The JSON.NET framework can convert XML to JSON, but it uses the @ sign in the JSON as the attribute.  I would rather remove this before sending it to the view.  What would be the best approach for this?

I know I can do a straight up replace, but an @ character may be relevant somewhere and shouldn't be replaced.  Is there a Regex for this?

```cs
public ActionResult Layout()
{
    var xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.XmlResolver = null;
    xml.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Navigation.xml"));
    return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xml, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
}
```

```js
{
  "Layout": {
    "Navigation": [
      {
        "@Type": "Menu",
        "@Title": "Dashboard"
      },
      {
        "@Type": "Menu",
        "@Route": "Events",
        "@Title": "Events",
        "Navigation": {
          "@Type": "Action",
          "@Route": "Event",
          "@Title": "+ Add Event",
          "@Order": "1",
          "Navigation": {
            "@Type": "Item",
            "@Route": "Event",
            "@Name": "Event",
            "Navigation": [
              {
                "@Route": "Pools",
                "@Type": "SubNavigation",
                "@Name": "Pools"
              },
              {
                "@Route": "Brackets",
                "@Type": "SubNavigation",
                "@Name": "Brackets"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It took me quite a while to find the right answer, so I thought I'd share:

```cs
var xDocument = XDocument.Parse("<xml><a attr=\"b\">c</a></xml>");
var builder = new StringBuilder();
JsonSerializer.Create().Serialize(new CustomJsonWriter(new StringWriter(builder)), xDocument);
var serialized = builder.ToString();

public class CustomJsonWriter : JsonTextWriter
{
    public CustomJsonWriter(TextWriter writer): base(writer){}

    public override void WritePropertyName(string name)
    {
        if (name.StartsWith("@") || name.StartsWith("#"))
        {
            base.WritePropertyName(name.Substring(1));
        }
        else
        {
            base.WritePropertyName(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```json
{"xml":{"a":{"attr":"b","text":"c"}}}
```

Comment: It is most correct and simplest solution... Overridden converter will take much more work to consider all cases.

Comment: I would also notify everyone not to forget about closing resources. (`CustomJsonWriter` and `StringWriter`)

Comment: If you would like to omit root object as in `JsonConvert.SerializeX[ml]Node`, instead of `JsonSerializer.Create()` use `JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new JsonConverter[] { new XmlNodeConverter { OmitRootObject = true }}})`

Comment: @N.Kudryavtsev - Your solution worked like a charm for me. I wanted to remove @ at the same remove the root object as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

I  went ahead and used this.  Let me know if there is a better way.

```cs
public ActionResult Layout()
{
    var xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.XmlResolver = null;
    xml.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Navigation.xml"));

    var jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xml, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    return Content(Regex.Replace(jsonText, "(?<=\")(@)(?!.*\":\\s )", string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
}
```

Comment: f you know that that's the only place the @ signs will show up in the json, string.replace works much faster or bigger documents

Comment: As mentioned by @yieio, this still does not work for values starting with `@`, e.g. `<test attr="@foo" />` will result in `{"test":{"attr":"foo"}}`.

Comment: This is not good for performance. It would be better to create a custom JsonTextWriter as answered elsewhere here.

Answer (score 1):

The Regex not always work great,when content has the @ character and in the first place,that will be replace too.
so I think`(?<!:)(\"@)(?!.\":\\s )` may be better.

Comment: This still does not work for values starting with `"@`, e.g. `<test attr="&quot;@foo" />` will result in `{"test":{"attr":"\"foo"}}`.

Comment: @Aristoteles Check my Regex, It's based on the above, but doesn't modify the content

Comment: A regex approach is not good for performance and potentially buggy.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to create your own `OneWayXmlNodeConverter` inheriting from `JsonConverter` and call `SerializeObject` instead of `SerializeXmlNode` like this:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(xmlNode, new OneWayXmlNodeConverter());
```

I call it "One Way" because I assume the default `XmlNodeConverter` adds the "@" sign so it can convert back to XML from the resulting JSON.

If you include the `JSON.NET` source in your project (as opposed to just the compiled library), an easy way to create the `OneWayXmlNodeConverter` is to copy the `XmlNodeConverter` code, remove the hard-coded "@" sign in the private `GetPropertyName` method, and save it as `OneWayXmlNodeConverter`.

Note: I know that your question is specific to "replacing" the "@" sign, but the linked [Preventing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897795/prevent-json-net-xml-converter-from-prefixing-attributes-with) variation of this question is marked as duplicate.

Comment: Your suggestion is very interesting, but did you try it?
When I tried to copy the XmlNodeConverter Code, I found that it depends heavily on internal interfaces, and classes, So I wasn't able to do what you suggested.
Did you managed to get it to work?

Comment: @PolaEdward I included the Json.Net source code in my project, so I was able to use the internals.  I will update my answer because you're right, if you're just using the library, it's *not* so easy :-)

Comment: Great, Updating the answers is always recommended :)
Actually I ended up with realizing that I have to embed the newtonsoft code to be able to edit it, stick to a specific version and lose all the future updates from the author, Or using regex, I decided to use regex

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the value of an attribute because of the '@' sign, do the following:

```
Navigation["@Type"]
```

Comment: Yes, but because of this you are losing performance when getting an attribute on the JSON

Answer (score 1):

Has been a while since this response, but this may still help someone.
Since you already have the XMLDocument, you can remove and convert the attributes before serializing it. I tried by either removing the attributes or converting them to elements.

```
public static void RemoveAllAttributes(XmlDocument xmlDocument)
{
     if (xmlDocument == null || !xmlDocument.HasChildNodes) return;

     foreach (var xmlElement in xmlDocument.SelectNodes(".//*").Cast<XmlElement>().Where(xmlElement => xmlElement.HasAttributes))
     {
          xmlElement.Attributes.RemoveAll();
     }
}

public static void ElementifyAllAttributes(XmlDocument xmlDocument)
{
    if (xmlDocument == null || !xmlDocument.HasChildNodes) return;

    foreach (var xmlElement in xmlDocument.SelectNodes(".//*").Cast<XmlElement>().Where(xmlElement => xmlElement.HasAttributes))
    {
        foreach (XmlAttribute xmlAttribute in xmlElement.Attributes)
        {
            xmlElement.AppendChild(xmlDocument.CreateElement(xmlAttribute.Name)).InnerText = xmlAttribute.Value;
        }

        xmlElement.Attributes.RemoveAll();
     }
}
```

And then;

```
private static string XmlToJson(XmlDocument xmlDocument)
{
    if (xmlDocument == null) return null;

    //Remove xml declaration
    xmlDocument.RemoveChild(xmlDocument.FirstChild);

    //Convert attributes to elements
    ElementifyAllAttributes(xmlDocument);

    return JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlDocument, Formatting.None, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my regex contribution, using lookaheads and lookbehinds to ensure it only occurs in the attribute field

`(?m)(?<=^\s+\")(@)(?=.+\"\:)`

Breakdown:

`(?m)` - Run in multiline mode

`(?<=^\s+\")` - Lookbehind to find the beginning of the line, one or more spaces, and a quote symbol

`(@)` - Match the @ after the quote

`(?=.+\"\:)` - Look ahead to match any character at least once, followed by another quote and then a colon

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the following regex, it the same as @yieio provided, but enhance to leave the content as is without any modifications, and affect only property names

```
var jString = Regex.Replace(
JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(content, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true),
 "(?<=(\\,\\\"|\\{\\\"))(@)(?!.*\\\":\\\\s )", String.Empty, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: When I tried this it doesn't work ie. it didn't seem to change anything. <test attr="foo" /> results in {"test":{"@attr":"foo"}}.

Comment: A regex approach is not good for performance and potentially buggy.

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON is indented, this could work:

```
Regex.Replace(result, @"(\s*)""@(.*)"":", @"$1""$2"":", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Confirmed to work in that it doesn't affect @ symbols in attribute content, either at the start, middle or end.

Comment: A regex approach is not good for performance and potentially buggy.

Answer (score -1):

First replace all "@" in your xml content with some placeholder (as example {{at_the_rate}}). Then use below code

```
JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc).Replace("@", "").Replace("{{at_the_rate}}", "@")
```

Comment: I hope you understand what will happen if your data has "{{at_the_rate}}".