# JSON.net has @ in the attribute names?

Tags: json, json.net

I am using JSON.NET and I want to convert from XML to JSON.

I am using JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(node) and I noticed that my json object has properties with @ in front of their names:

So for example:
   If I have:

```
<channel id="999" name="XXX" sid="8294" type="Digital TV" />
```

the JSON object is:

```
{ "@id": "999", @name="XXX" etc
```

Why am I getting "@" inserted in the JSON and is there a way I can avoid the "@" character being inserted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON.NET and Replacing @ Sign in XML to JSON converstion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278577/json-net-and-replacing-sign-in-xml-to-json-converstion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think thats just the way json.net works regarding the @ signs. You can always run a regex on the json string and replace them. Theres an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278577/json-net-and-replacing-sign-in-xml-to-json-converstion)

Comment: Thanks for that. I wasn't sure if I was doing something wrong.

Comment: if you know that that's the only place the @ signs will show up in the json, string.replace works much faster or bigger documents