# Prevent JSON.NET Xml converter from prefixing attributes with '@'

Tags: javascript, vb.net, json, knockout.js, json.net

I'm trying to convert some XML data into JSON to use with KnockoutJS.  After a bit of research I decided to go with JSON.NET to convert my `XNode` tree to a JSON String.  I convert the XML tree by calling

```
JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(result, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, True)
```

which gives me something like

```
"Header": {
"@id": "3",
"@name": "General",
"Property": [
  {
    "@id": "76",
...
```

Trying to reference things like `@name` causes my KnockoutJS templates to break.  I would just remove all instances of `@` from the string, but it exists in the data as well.

Is there any easy way to prevent JSON.NET from putting the `@` symbol on attributes?