# Convert JSON to XDocument using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, json, xml, json.net

I am able to do conversion from JSON to XML and vice versa using the default implementations.

However, Json.Net prefixes the XML attributes with an `@`. This can only be accessed in JavaScript by using `root['@myAttribute']`. For performance reasons, I rename the attributes using a custom `JsonTextWriter` and instead prefix them with a `$` so I can access them by using `root.$myAttribute`.

#### My custom JsonTextWriter

```
public class CustomJsonTextWriter : JsonTextWriter
{
    public CustomJsonTextWriter(TextWriter writer) : base(writer) { }

    public override void WritePropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        if (propertyName.StartsWith("@"))
            base.WritePropertyName("$" + propertyName.Substring(1));
        else
            base.WritePropertyName(propertyName);
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
public static string ConvertXDocumentToJson(XDocument xDoc)
{
    // Usage of the CustomJsonTextWriter to write the XML doc in JSON format prefixing attributes with "$" instead of "@".
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    JsonSerializer.Create().Serialize(new CustomJsonTextWriter(new StringWriter(builder)), xDoc);
    return builder.ToString();            
}
```

From this point, I am able to convert from XML quite efficiently and in the required JSON format (attributes prefixed as wished).

---

#### The problem

The problem occurs on the reverse conversion, JSON to XML, as fields that are supposed to be XML attributes (prefixed with `@`) are still prefixed with `$`.

I know there are ways to correct this by using Regex and String.replace, but I don't want to do an extra read of the whole JSON again before doing the conversion.

#### Preferred solution

I would like to have a `CustomJsonTextReader` which could output an XML, but by specifying that the prefix char is "$" and not "@". I was expecting a kind of override of a class (JsonTextReader) where I could do something similar :

```
public override void ReadPropertyName(string propertyName)
{
    // pseudo-code
    if(propertyName.startsWith("$")) // instead of "@"
        CreateXmlAttribute(propertyName.substring(1));
}
```

Comment: If StackCodeReview is only for code review, then no. I want to find a solution on how to write a custom converter for JSON to XML that respects / mimics the currently used one by Newtonsoft.

Comment: How are you exposing your API? If it is through WebAPI you don't have to do anything. WebAPI looks at the `Accept-Encoding` header of the request and returns the correct format.

Comment: You've got code that works, albeit not permorning to your needs, but that is where code review will help you and you can ask that question with less fear of reprise.  SO is not a code writing service for you

Comment: @MichaelCoxon The problem is not about exposing the API, it is about reading a JSON where fields are prefixed with "$" instead of "@" to convert them to XML attributes. Imagine that this scenario could only imply reading a local file.

Comment: @CodeWarrior I am not expecting a writing service, but rather an idea on how to implement this IF possible. I've been searching for hours with no luck, so maybe someone on SO has encountered the same problem and solved it. Link close-related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278577/json-net-and-replacing-sign-in-xml-to-json-converstion

Comment: There are serialize xml and deserialize xml commands in `JsonConvert`. Is there any reason you are not using these? (I don't know about how they work)

Comment: @MichaelCoxon The sample I provided converts from XML to JSON. But for the other way, I use the `JsonConvert` that you mention. It works great if attributes are prefixed with "@", but since I got the "$" prefix I have to replace every "$" to "@" before using `JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json)`.

Comment: I do not understand why the downvotes, my question seems legit. Any explanation for downvoting this ?

Comment: Ok so is there a reason why you are prefixing JSON with '$'? It seems that (from what I can gather from the question) that the only reason you are doing this is so you can access the object using JavaScript object notation

Comment: @MichaelCoxon That's exactly the point. The server (and other modules around it) access the object using JS object notation, and from some tests it is more efficient than accessing them with `["attribute"]` notation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154335/discussion-between-michael-coxon-and-jacks).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154354/discussion-between-michael-coxon-and-jacks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need a `JsonTextReader` to do the reverse...

#### Reader

```
public class CustomJsonReader : JsonTextReader
{
    public CustomJsonReader(TextReader reader) : base(reader) { }

    public override object Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (TokenType != JsonToken.PropertyName)
            {
                return base.Value;
            }

            var propertyName = base.Value.ToString();

            if (propertyName.StartsWith("$"))
            {
                return $"@{propertyName.Substring(1)}";
            }
            else
            {
                return base.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
var xmlDoc = JsonSerializer.Create().Deserialize<XmlDocument>(
    new CustomJsonReader(new StringReader(json)));

// get the string value if needed...
var builder = new StringBuilder();
xmlDoc.Save(new StringWriter(builder ));

var xml = outbuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you very much for your time, explanations and edits @MichaelCoxon !