# Covert XML string to json

Tags: c#, json, xml, serialization

I have a string xml

```
                    ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                    <Entities TotalResults="64">
                       <Entity Type="test-set">
                          <ChildrenCount>
                             <Value>0</Value>
                          </ChildrenCount>
                          <Fields>
                             <Field Name="name">
                                <Value>default</Value>
                             </Field>
                             <Field Name="id">
                                <Value>0</Value>
                             </Field>
                          </Fields>
                          <RelatedEntities />
                       </Entity>
                       <Entity Type="test-set">
                          <ChildrenCount>
                             <Value>0</Value>
                          </ChildrenCount>                          
                          <RelatedEntities />
                       </Entity>
                       <singleElementCollection>false</singleElementCollection>
                    </Entities>
```

I am using below code to convert xml sting to json and used XMLDocument and JsonConvert.serializexmlNode().

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();            
string xml = objHttpWebClient._retunResponseStream("http://test:8080/test-sets?fields=ID,Name", "GET", ASCIIEncoding.UTF8, cc);
doc.LoadXml(xml);
string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
return jsonText;
```

I am getting output like below

```
                                    {
                    "?xml": {
                        "@version": "1.0",
                        "@encoding": "UTF-8",
                        "@standalone": "yes"
                    },
                    "Entities": {
                        "@TotalResults": "64",
                        "Entity": [{
                            "@Type": "test-set",
                            "ChildrenCount": {
                                "Value": "0"
                            },
                            "Fields": {
                                "Field": [{
                                    "@Name": "name",
                                    "Value": "default"
                                },
                                {
                                    "@Name": "id",
                                    "Value": "0"
                                }]
                            },
                            "RelatedEntities": null
                        },
                        {
                            "@Type": "test-set",
                            "ChildrenCount": {
                                "Value": "0"
                            },

                        .........
```

...............................................................

however, I want to ignore '@' and 
                    {
                        "?xml": {
                            "@version": "1.0",
                            "@encoding": "UTF-8",
                            "@standalone": "yes"
                        },

part from output json.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON.NET and Replacing @ Sign in XML to JSON converstion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278577/json-net-and-replacing-sign-in-xml-to-json-converstion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply remove the first child from the XML document before serializing it into json. It would look something like this.

```
doc.RemoveChild(doc.FirstChild);
```

This should do the trick.